# `cordova run android` will start the app, but won't install latest version

Tags: android, cordova

App works fine in emulator. I also emailed myself the apk and installed it on my phone, and it works fine.

When I run `cordova run android` on my laptop it says it installs it correctly (lie) and then launches it successfully (true).

It never copies it from my laptop to the phone.

How can I fix this? How can I debug this?

Is there some app id or app name I need to change? Where?

Phone is 4.1.1 , do I need to specify a target level?

USB debug is on on phone, as well as allowing apps from unknown sources.

If all else fails, how can I copy the apk easily to my phone?

Comment: which files are you modifying? `yourprojectfolder->www->index.html` OR `yourprojectfolder->platform->android->......->www->index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bizarre but `adb install my.apk` works just fine but `cordova run android` doesn't work at all.

Otherwise, you can install a file browser app on your phone. Copy apk to USB storage on phone, then install via file browser.